# How to redirect folder links to the homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I'm using WordPress and I have created a few folders for uploading files through FTP.

I would like to redirect folder links to my set homepage, for example: [this link](http://www.zensabook.com/download/sample) shows the Apache Server at Port 80 which I need to redirect it to the homepage.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an index page in the root of the folder with

```
<?PHP
    header('location:location/to/homepage');
?>
```

This will be the easiest thing to do.

You could also look into using some [`.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) files to restrict access to a page and send them to a 403 error page or send it to the homepage.